# Give month in text from date for more then 300.000 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've a column of dates in my table more than 300.000 rows formatted as `dd-mm-yyyy`. now I'll from all rows the month in text and the year. How can I do that on the fast way?

**Example table:**

```
+----------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
|  Number  |    Date    |   Hours  | Month in text | Year |
+----------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
| 1        | 01-01-2010 | 0:00:00  | January       | 2010 |
| 2        | 01-02-2010 | 0:00:05  | February      | 2010 |
| ...      | ...        | ...      | ...           | ...  |
| 325.696  | 01-12-2014 | 23:59:55 | December      | 2014 |
+----------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
```

I'm not so good whit working with Excel. So can you give me also a formula to calculate it. Is there also a fast way to calculate that for all the rows?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this a growing document?

The reason I am asking is that you have a limit when you reach roughly 1048000 rows, if you plan to use this for a few years you should perhaps plan ahead so it doesn't come as a surprise and create a problem down the line.

If the document grows linear, you could keep this up for a long time, but if it is business related and grows exponentially or experience a growth spurt, you might need to migrate to a database and that is always easier to do in a planned manned, not out of panic when you realize that you just hit the bottom of your sheet

Comment: @JonCarlstedt: The document I have is not growing. First the excel file was a csv file. But for analytic calculations it is easier to use excel. But thanks to say it that there is an limit on the rows you can use in excel. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Excel on this machine, so this may not be exactly right,
but something like this should work.

`=text(a1,"mmmm")`

For the year:

`=year(a1)`

Comment: 1) I'm sorry, I was wrong... :-( It was because, anyone used another formula that was more difficult than that. / 2) How can you slide that formula for more than 300,000 rows? / 3) I've tried to use a comma as separator for the formula but that didn't work. Now I use a dot comma as separator. I'm not sure but I think it is because the different language and notation than the USA. I use the Belgian (European) notation.

Comment: (2) Are you talking about using that little dot in the corner that you drag? I never use that thing. Copy the formula and paste it into the target cells. Or use control-D to duplicate. (3) As far as I know, a comma is standard to separate items in Excel formulas.

Comment: 2) yes, it is that little dot. Thanks for the hint for duplicate it. 3) Yes, a comma didn't work by me. So if you say, a comma is standard in USA, I believe you. I know that there is a different between comma and dot comma separations in Belgium (Europe) and the USA. Here we use a dot comma also as separation for csv files. In Europe we use a comma for decimal notations. Example: In Europe: 5,3 / In USA: 5.3

Comment: Um, that symbol you're calling a “dot comma” is usually known as a “period”.

Answer (score 1):

If the original date is in cell `A1`, then in `C1` you have to put `=A1`. Format cells as *Custom* and put **mmmm**.